# NSMutableArray Only Shows One Object

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I Have mutableArray of 5 values( A,B,C,D,E). When I compare object with function [ Aa objectAtIndex:something]; .It only shows object which I have added last . Other objects are showing null index. I'm also show all the object in MutableArray it shows all the Values .But when I compare it, it just shows last index only.

```
    int j=0;
    mu_annid=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    while([strTemp length]!=0) 
     { 
     strTemp=[strTemp ]
     strTemp=[strTemp substringFromIndex:0]; 
       if([strTemp rangeOfString:@","].location==NSNotFound)
        {
          [mu_annid addObject:strTemp];break;}
          j=[strTemp rangeOfString:@","].location;
          [mu_annid addObject:[strTemp substringToIndex:j]]; 
          strTemp=[strTemp substringFromIndex:++j];
          j=0;
        }
         for(int r=0;r<[mu_annid count];++r)
         {
         NSLog(@"mu_annid[%i]:%@",r,[mu_annid objectAtIndex:r]);
         NSLog(@"strTemp:%@",strTemp);
         }

      }
```

Comment: can you post your code please?

Comment: You seems to have a coding problem, so show some code if you want some help.

Comment: Without any code reference no one can answer what issue you are facing.

Comment: int j=0;mu_annid=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; while([strTemp length]!=0) { strTemp=[strTemp ]strTemp=[strTemp substringFromIndex:0]; if([strTemp rangeOfString:@","].location==NSNotFound){[mu_annid addObject:strTemp];break;}j=[strTemp rangeOfString:@","].location;[mu_annid addObject:[strTemp substringToIndex:j]]; strTemp=[strTemp substringFromIndex:++j];j=0;}for(int r=0;r<[mu_annid count];++r){NSLog(@"mu_annid[%i]:%@",r,[mu_annid objectAtIndex:r]);NSLog(@"strTemp:%@",strTemp);

Answer (score 0):

This was faced by me also. solution is
To work with the mutable array first you have to alloc it.

```
NSMutableArray * xyz=[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

After doing this do all the necessary operations on it and you will get all the objects.

Comment: int j=0;mu_annid=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  while([strTemp length]!=0)
  {
   strTemp=[strTemp ]strTemp=[strTemp substringFromIndex:0]; if([strTemp rangeOfString:@","].location==NSNotFound){[mu_annid addObject:strTemp];break;}j=[strTemp rangeOfString:@","].location;[mu_annid addObject:[strTemp substringToIndex:j]];  strTemp=[strTemp substringFromIndex:++j];j=0;}for(int r=0;r<[mu_annid count];++r){NSLog(@"mu_annid[%i]:%@",r,[mu_annid objectAtIndex:r]);NSLog(@"strTemp:%@",strTemp);

Comment: Please post your code in your question itself so that it can be easily understood.